# How can I use a global variable in Angular4+ without inject as a dependency?

Tags: angular, global-variables

There is a third party old js library based on jQuery, I want to use it in Angular Service or Component, but I don't want to inject it as a global variable, because, if I do so, angular will package the "third party old js library" as part of output js which cause an IE11 compatible issue.

Is there a way use this library without angular told me this "variable can not find:?

"error TS2304: Cannot find name 'jabberwerx'."

Thanks

Comment: https://netbasal.com/loading-external-libraries-on-demand-in-angular-9dad45701801

Comment: To avoid "cannot find name" error, you can access global variable via window - `window['someLib']`

Comment: @taras-d Thanks a lot for you simple solution.